# Unable to add user data into MySQL table by phonegap

Tags: php, mysql, cordova, registration

I'm developing a phonegap app and currently trying to implement a registration form for users to sign up, then add their username, email and password into MySQL phpadmin database. However, after many trials, user data didn't add into sql database and I'm not so sure where the problem is.

I have one connect.php file: `

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

if (!$connection){

die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());

}

$select_db = mysql_select_db('test');

if (!$select_db){

die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());

}
?>
```

`

and another signup.php file: `

```
require('connect.php');

// If the values are posted, insert them into the database.

if (isset($_POST['signup-username']) && isset($_POST['signup-email']) && isset($_POST['signup-password'])){

    $signup-username = $_POST['signup-username'];

    $signup-email = $_POST['signup-email'];

    $signup-password = $_POST['signup-password'];



    $query = "INSERT INTO `signup` (Username, E-mail, Password) VALUES ('$signup-username', '$signup-email', '$signup-password')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result){

        $msg = "User Created Successfully.";

    }

}

?>
```

`

Comment: Your code appears to be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and additionally is using the depreciated 'mysql' extension which will be removed in the future, as mentioned by Nxtmind. It's suggested to use 'mysqli' or 'pdo' instead.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you dump the $_POST array prior to the if statement, are the proper values present? If you print $query, does it look like a proper SQL statement?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch if I use the extension, do I still need to use MySQL on phpadmin?

Comment: did you put that code inside the phonegap app? phonegap doesn't run PHP code

Comment: @jcesarmobile Oh ya I put inside phonegap, So I should instead put insidea xampp file (sql server I'm using)?

Comment: You have to put the server code (PHP) on a server, and you communicate with the server from javascript using XHR calls (AJAX)

Comment: @jcesarmobile I just now finished this part, but then got error message `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\signup.php on line 6`

Comment: You can't name the variables with a - on it, use camelcase $signupUsername or underscore $signup_username (not sure which one is the convention for PHP)

Comment: Yes, each of those extensions I mention is a PHP library for accessing MySQL. phpMyAdmin isn't involved here regardless; it's a tool for administrators to manage their MySQL database, not something you'd access from your program.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the Mysql Improved extension, http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: but I need to run the app on eclipse emulator